# How call a stored function in a void* variable in a structure in c++ (callback)

Tags: c++

I have a void* variable in a structure that stores a function address, now i want to call the function with that address:

```
int randomNumber = 0;

int Random(){
    randomNumber++;
    return randomNumber;
}

struct CStructure{
    int rep;
    void* functionRandom;
};

CStructure* ConstructorCS(CStructure** myCS, int rep, int(*myFunctionRandom)(void)){
    *myCS = (CStructure*) malloc (sizeof(CStructure));
    (*myCS)->rep = rep;
    (*myCS)->functionRandom = &myFunctionRandom;
}

void ExecuteCStructure(CStructure* myCS){
    int counter = 0;
    int randomNumbers[myCS->rep];
    char* text;
    while(counter < (myCS->rep)){
        randomNumbers[counter] = myCS->functionRandom; //here i must receive a number from teh function
        printf("\n number generated by the function: %d", randomNumbers[counter]);
    }
}

test01(){
    CStructure* code;
    ConstructorCS(&code, 3, &Random);
    ExecuteCStructure(code)
}
```

How would be the correct way to execute or call the function stored in the structure in the function **ExecuteCStructure**... thnks..

Comment: why you don't use `int(*functionRandom)(void)`? It let you call it like normal function. (and there is no reason store it as `void*`)

Comment: i don't use that because i want to store the addres of my function in some way in order to execute later is the meanin of my test, i stored in a void but maybe i could store it in other variable or something...

Comment: `std::function`? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

Comment: @ErickVargas `int(*functionRandom)(void)` is a function *pointer*, not a function. It basically store a address of your function (just like you said).

Comment: Function pointers are not data pointers. Converting a function pointer to `void*` is **undefined behaviour**. There are several other instances of UB and bad practice in your code. Are you sure you are using C++? This looks an awful lot like C.

Comment: mmm i'm learning c++ which are my bad practices i'd love to see my mistakes... except in Random() it's just an example...

Comment: ¿¿¿Like i said i want to store a pointer to function  in my struct, how can i do that???

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast you function pointer, so that the compiler will know how to call the function.

Here is one way to do it:

```
randomNumbers[counter] = (int (*)())myCS->functionRandom();
```

The `(int (*)())` casts `myCS->functionRandom` to a function that gets void and returns int, and of course you need to call it with parenthesis.

**EDIT**

I haven't checked it, but I believe the cast has a higher priority over the last parenthesis. That is, it is understood as so:

```
((int (*)())myCS->functionRandom) ();
```

If this is not the case, you will need also to add the parenthesis wrapping it all, to designate a stand alone function..

Comment: I used: 
- ((int (*)())myCS->functionRandom) ()
also
- (((int (*)())myCS->functionRandom) ())
It compiles but there is a runtime error...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer i was looking for, how to store a addres to a function in a structure:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <math.h>

int randomNumber = 0;

int Random(){
    randomNumber++;
    return randomNumber;
}

struct CStructure{
    int rep;
    int (*FunctionRandom) ();
};

CStructure* ConstructorCS(CStructure** myCS, int rep, int(*myFunctionRandom)(void)){
    *myCS = (CStructure*) malloc (sizeof(CStructure));
    (*myCS)->rep = rep;
    (*myCS)->FunctionRandom = myFunctionRandom;
}

void ExecuteCStructure(CStructure* myCS){
    int counter = 0;
    int randomNumbers[myCS->rep];
    char* text;
    while(counter < (myCS->rep)){
        //here i  receive a number from the function
        randomNumbers[counter] = myCS->FunctionRandom();
        printf("\n number generated by the function: %d", randomNumbers[counter]);
        counter++;
    }
}

int test01(){
    CStructure* code;
    ConstructorCS(&code, 3, &Random);
    ExecuteCStructure(code);
}

int main(){
    test01();
}
```